# Is there a way I can add more variety of sounds to a mob?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-resource-packs

I'm trying to make a recourse pack that includes an extra files of sounds to the villager. But I cannot seem to make the villagers say the files I've made.
They're all labled as "idle#" just like the other idle files for the villagers. I've put these as "idle4", "idle5" etc...

If anyone out there knows a way to make more variants to how many sounds a mob can play, I'd like to know a way to do it!

Comment: Your sounds 1 to 3 work as expected? Then this might maybe not be possible in Vanilla Minecraft. Have you tried OptiFine? It adds some features to resource packs, maybe also that one.

Comment: It is possible, albeit complex. I'll need to do some testing at home before I can write an answer out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's definitely possible, though requires some file management.

---

1. In your resource pack, navigate to the `assets/minecraft` folder.
2. Create a file called `sounds.json`. You will need a text editor that understands `json` files.
3. Navigate to the `indexes` folder, and find the version you're creating a resource pack for.
4. Ctrl+F for "sounds"; you should find a long hexadecimal string. Note this down.
5. Now, head to your `.minecraft` folder (Open the Run program, run `%appdata%/.minecraft`). Search for the hexadecimal in that folder.
6. Copy the contents of that file to your `sounds.json` file.
7. There should be something like the following:

```
"entity.villager.hurt": {
"sounds": [
"mob/villager/hit1",
"mob/villager/hit2",
"mob/villager/hit3"
}
```

8. It's now simple to add sounds. Simply copypaste `"mob/villager/hitN"`, increasing N by 1 until you reach the number of sounds you want.
9. Then, in the sounds folder for your resource pack, you can name your sounds Hit4.ogg, Hit5.ogg, etc.

---

This should work for every sound file in the game. For a list of sound files, check out [this page on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sounds.json).